# Get list of supported opcodes

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

Is there a way to get a list of supported opcodes for a given architecture? Such as a listing in /proc similar to /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: I'm quite sure the answer is 'no'. "Opcodes" are an assembly-language construct suggested by the CPU mfr. However, there is no reason that assemblers must follow that convention. The _real_ opcodes are in binary and "mean" something only to that CPU. Various opcodes have different modes of behavior depending on the nature of the operands, so an "add" might have 15 different binary opcode representations.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, perhaps look at the manufacturers' web sites - http://ark.intel.com/ and http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/processors and http://www.arm.com/products/processors/ - look up the processor or chipset you're interested in, see which instruction sets it supports, and refer to their architecture manuals to see the detailed list of instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to assembly instructions the two general approaches are:

Check desired functionality against flags output from cpuinfo, example output:

> flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
>   pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx
>   pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl
>   xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor
>   ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2
>   x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand
>   lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi
>   flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms
>   invpcid

The second approach is to attempt to execute the assembly instruction and see if something bad happens.

As already stated the actual opcodes are not possible to see as the assembly instructions (on intel at least) are translated into op-codes which are executed by the processor.

Comment: The mentioned flags are simply features rather than opcodes. And I suggest some reading before executing statements like `lab0: lock loop lab0`.

Comment: @ott--, nice loop :-) That being said, the flags indeed define features but that gives us the list of supported assembler instructions. As far as I know there are clear lists of flags vs instructions in the docs.